# How to change font size and font of static control when the property is transparent

Tags: c++, mfc, font-size, transparent

I create two CStatic controls. One property is set to transparent mode; another one is normal.
After I change font size, one is OK, it is changed, but the set transparent mode one is not changed in size.

Does anybody know why?

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
/* Resource File */
LTEXT           "This Is Normal Text.",IDC_FONT2,7,119,303,21,WS_BORDER
LTEXT           "This Include Transparent.",IDC_FONT,7,7,306,21,WS_BORDER | NOT WS_GROUP | WS_TABSTOP,WS_EX_TRANSPARENT


/* FontTest.CPP */
class CFontSizeDlg : public CDialogEx
{
public:
    CStatic m_myFont;
    CStatic m_myFont2;
}

/* FontTest.CPP */
void CFontSizeDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_FONT, m_myFont);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_FONT2, m_myFont2);
}

void CFontSizeDlg::OnBnClickedButton2()
{
    CFont hNewFont;
    LOGFONT lf;                        // Used to create the CFont.

    CFont *currentFont = GetFont();
    currentFont->GetLogFont(&lf);
    lf.lfHeight = 25;
    lf.lfWidth = 10;

    hNewFont.DeleteObject();
    hNewFont.CreateFontIndirect(&lf);    // Create the font.

     // Use the font to paint a control.
    m_myFont2.SetFont(&hNewFont);
    m_myFont.SetFont(&hNewFont);

    // hNewFont.Detach(); // will create GDI leak
    hNewFont.DeleteObject();
}
```

Comment: `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` doesn't actually make a control transparent, it's poorly named. It merely changes the order of painting so that you can simulate transparency in the `WM_PAINT` message.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that the scope of the 'new' font is the same as the static control(s).  In your example, the font is destroyed when the button event handler is done.  Try making hNewFont a member variable and setting it once.

Comment: Thank for your apply. But still can't solve this problem. 
Opps, My final code is like this.
// hNewFont.Detach(); // This will create GDI leak //
 hNewFont.DeleteObject();

Comment: As I stated in my answer, you should make the font object a member variable of the class and define it once (eg. in OnInitDialog) and destroy it when the dialog is destroyed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My question is why difference between "Transparent mode" and "normal mode" in my case ?

Comment: Thanks, I got the solution . It is that to create New CStatic Class, and put new font routine in OnPaint Function.

Comment: HI @ybc45 Can you tell me how you solved your problem??